# How to query the system clock?

Tags: stm32

How can I query the system clock on an STM32F3xx to make sure it is what I intended to set it as?  It appears that I suddenly am operating much slower than before.

It looks like the HAL API (V1.5.2 via `HAL_Driver/Src/stm323xx_hal.c`) changed and I can no longer:

```
#include "stm32f3xx_hal_rcc.h"
...
RCC_ClocksTypeDef clocks;
RCC_GetClocksFreq(&clocks);
__NOP(); // <- Breakpoint here and inspect local variable
```

Comment: You've read the [documentation](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/a6/79/73/ae/6e/1c/44/14/DM00122016.pdf/files/DM00122016.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00122016.pdf) for the STM32F3 HAL?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing anything in the API in terms of macros I can use.  The just echo back my same configs I've provided and not the result of those configs.

Comment: So `HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq()` on page 506 doesn't do the job for you? As long as your crystal frequency is as you defined it in stm32f3xx_hal_conf.h, it should give you an accurate result.

Comment: You're right.  Thanks.  I was looking at `2.12.2.2 System clock initialization` in the documentation and my searches across the project space somehow weren't general enough to catch that.  SysClk != SysClock.  If you convert to an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
volatile uint32_t SysClockFreq = HAL_RCC_GetSysClockFreq();
  __NOP(); // <- Breakpoint here
```

You may also be able to write an inline assembly loop and measure the execution time with a GPIO on an oscilloscope:

To approximately wait 1600 iterations in two nested for loops:

```
asm(
    "MOV  R8, #0      \n\t" // Initialize the counter
    "loop0:           \n\t"
    "ADD  R8, R8, #1  \n\t" // Increment it

    "MOV  R9, #0      \n\t" // Initialize the counter
    "loop1:           \n\t"
    "ADD  R9, R9, #1  \n\t" // Increment it
    "CMP  R9, #4000   \n\t" // Check the limit
    "BLE  loop1       \n\t" // Continue looping if not finished
    ";"
    "CMP  R8, #4000   \n\t" // Check the limit
    "BLE  loop0       \n\t" // Continue looping if not finished
    ";                \n\t"
  );
```

Comment: I believe this should say "1600000 iterations in two nested for loops" (not 1600), because it counts 4000 times to 4000 and 4000*4000=16000000.